# MySql getConnection.Exception, Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Not found

Tags: java, exception, model-view-controller, connection, classnotfoundexception

I'm having the error with class not found exception whenever I try to call getConnection from ProductDataBean. Here's the code:

**Product.java**

```
ProductDataBean pdb = new ProductDataBean();
Connection connect = pdb.getConnection(); // ClassNotFoundException on this line)
```

**ProductDataBean.java**

```
   package cart;
   import java.io.*;
   import java.sql.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class ProductDataBean implements Serializable{


public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String connURL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlinecart?user=root&password=teck1577130713";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL); 
    return conn;
}
}
```

I will be thankful if u can help me solve this problem! :)

Comment: Have you added mysql-connector.jar file to your classpath ??

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
I add this file to my build path. I'm not sure what u meant by classpath...Do I have to add classpath? how?

Comment: can you paste your exception here ? and i was writing build path, but by mistakenly i wrote classpath

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
 org.apache.jsp.ShowProductCatalog_jsp._jspService(ShowProductCatalog_jsp.java:166)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 cart.ProductDataBean.getConnection(ProductDataBean.java:12)
 cart.Product.getProductList(Product.java:14)

Comment: org.apache.jsp.ShowProductCatalog_jsp._jspService(ShowProductCatalog_jsp.java:88)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: Your Driver class is not found, if you are using eclipse, be sure your jar is in webinf/lib folder

Comment: So What should I do? Put sql-connector.bin.jar into webinf/lib folder?

Comment: Yeah, if u are using eclipse, you are required to put your mysql connector jar inside web-inf/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be not copying your **Mysql connector.jar** inside **WEB-INF/lib** folder